# PHPからMySQLへのinsert文でエラーは出ないのにinsertされない

Tags: php, mysql

PHPからMySQLへのinsert文でエラーは出ないのにinsertされません なぜでしょう？

追記

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
 
if(empty($_POST)) {
    header("Location: pdo_form.html");
    exit();
}else{
    //名前入力判定
    if (!isset($_POST['yourname'])  || $_POST['yourname'] === "" ){
        $errors['name'] = "名前が入力されていません。";
    }
}
 
if(count($errors) === 0){
    
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test2;charset=utf8';
    $user = 'root2';
    $password = 'pass2';
 
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO name (name) VALUES (:name)");
    
        if($statement){
            $yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
            //プレースホルダへ実際の値を設定する
            $statement->bindValue(':name', $yourname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
            if(!$statement->execute()){
                $errors['error'] = "登録失敗しました。";
            }
            
            //データベース接続切断
            $dbh = null;    
        }
    
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        print('Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        $errors['error'] = "データベース接続失敗しました。";
    }
}
 
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>登録画面</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 
<?php if (count($errors) === 0): ?>
<p><?=htmlspecialchars($yourname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."さんで登録いたしました。"?></p>
<?php elseif(count($errors) > 0): ?>
<?php
foreach($errors as $value){
    echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
 
</body>
</html>
```

追記

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

を追加しましたがエラーは出ずinsertもされません

Comment: PHPからではなくMySQLに直接クエリを発行した場合はどうなりますか？ / 「エラーが出ない」と言いますが、エラーが出た時にハンドリングするようなPHPのコードを書いてなければ恐らく何も表示されません。実際のコードを提示するなど詳しい情報を追記してください。

Comment: My SQL単体では可能です コードは追記のとおりです

Comment: 例外処理を記述していますが、PDOがエラーがしたときに例外を投げるにはモードを変更する必要があります。[PDOのエラー処理](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.error-handling.php)を設定してみて、エラーが発生しないかもう一度確認してみてください

Comment: 質問者さんと同一人物と思われる方から編集提案が来ていますが、本来質問者さんであれば自由に編集ができます。アカウントが二つになってしまった場合は、アカウントを[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)から統合し、再度編集をお試しください。